# Compare the length in Euclidean and Hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For any $r \in(0,1)$ consider the length of the curve $\gamma:[0,2 \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times[0, \infty)$ given by $\gamma(t)=r\left(\cos (t) e_{1}+\right.\left.\sin (t) e_{2}\right)+e_{2}$ with respect to the Euclidean metric and also with respect to the hyperbolic metric. Which
is bigger? Is this true for all values of $r$ or is there some point where both lengths agree?

This is what I have so far,
$$\dot{\gamma}(t) = r(-sin(t)e_1 + cos(t)e_2 $$
My lecture notes state that
$$
L(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}|\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g}(\gamma(t)) d t
$$
Where $|\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g}(\gamma(t)) =\sqrt{ g(p)(\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))}$. For the Euclidean case this is
$$ |\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g_{Euclid}}(\gamma(t)) = \sqrt{\langle \dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)\rangle} = \sqrt{(r^2cos^2(t) + r^2sin^2(t)) } =r$$
So $$
L_{Euclid}(\gamma)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}r d t = 2\pi r
$$
Then for the Hyperbolic case, again according to my lecture notes $|\dot{\gamma}(t)|_{g_H}(\gamma(t)) =\sqrt{ g(p)(\dot{\gamma}(t),\dot{\gamma}(t))} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{y^2}\langle \dot{\gamma}(t), \dot{\gamma}(t)\rangle}$.
Now I am not sure what to fill in for $y$, I thought it would be $r sin(t) + 1$ but that leads to an integral I cannot solve.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: My apologies Didier, I should have added that immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed put $y=1+r\sin t$. You get then an integral

$$ L_{hyper}(\gamma) = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r}{1+r\sin t} dt$$

There are methods to calculate this integral (for example the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) and [countour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_3_%E2%80%93_trigonometric_integrals)), but you can also notice that with the shift $t\to t+\pi$ and using the periodicity of sine fucntion we get

$$ L_{hyper}(\gamma) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{r}{1+r\sin (t+\pi)} dt = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{r}{1- r\sin t} dt = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r}{1- r\sin t} dt$$
so
\begin{align} 2L_{hyper}(\gamma) &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r}{1+r\sin t} dt + \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{r}{1- r\sin t} dt =\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left(\frac{r}{1+r\sin t} + \frac{r}{1- r\sin t} \right)dt =\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{2r}{1-r^2\sin^2 t} dt > \\
&> \int_{0}^{2\pi} 2r dt = 2L_{Euclid}(\gamma)\end{align}
so
$$ L_{hyper}(\gamma) > L_{Euclid}(\gamma)$$